# Why @Qualifier annotation does not work with final member variable

Tags: java, spring, lombok, final, spring-annotations

I noticed that the `@Qualifier` annotation does not work with `final` member variable.
In the code below,

- if the `Vehicle` member variable of `Person` is declared as `final`, an exception is thrown;
- otherwise, no exception is thrown (but the    `vehicle` is null).

Can anyone please explain why?

```
// 2 Vehicle beans are annotated by @Qualifier;
@Configuration
public class Config 
{
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("vehicle1")
  Vehicle vehicle1() {
    var veh = new Vehicle();
    veh.setName("Benz");
    return veh;
  }

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("vehicle2")
  Vehicle vehicle2() {
    var veh = new Vehicle();
    veh.setName("BMW");
    return veh;
  }
}

// Person has a final member variable Vehicle
@Component
@Data
public class Person 
{
  private String name="Mike";

  @Qualifier("vehicle2")
  private final Vehicle vehicle;
}
```

Springboot complain about NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException:

> - No qualifying bean of type 'project1.Vehicle' available: expected
>   single matching bean but found 2: vehicle1,vehicle2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is closely related to lombok, which is quite common.

### What I would suggest for such problem is **to look at the processed class**.

If you are using IntelliJ, go to the project build directory to open the class file.

### 1. if the Vechicle member variable of Person is declared as final, an exception is thrown;

The processed class is:

```java
@Component
public class Person {
    private String name = "Mike";
    @Qualifier("vehicle2")
    private final Vehicle vehicle;

    public Person(final Vehicle vehicle) {
        this.vehicle = vehicle;
    }
    ...
}
```

We see that injection is through the constructor in this case, and `@Qualifier` is neglected. Hence we will see `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` as we does not specify which bean to use.

### 2. otherwise, no exception is thrown (but the vehicle is null).

This time the processed class is:

```java
@Component
public class Person {
    private String name = "Mike";
    @Qualifier("vehicle2")
    private Vehicle vehicle;

    public Person() {
    }
    ...
}
```

`vehicle` does not appear in the constructor this time and there is no `@Autowired` for `vehicle, so no injection is preformed and it is null.

### How to make it work?

To begin, it is not common to use `@Data` with Spring bean, `@Data` is usually used by DTO. And in favour of constructor injection, I will modify `Person` like below

```java
@Component
public class Person {
    private String name = "Mike";
    private final Vehicle vehicle;
    public Person(@Qualifier("vehicle2") Vehicle vehicle) {
        this.vehicle = vehicle;
    }
    // ... getter setter omitted
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer -- not only the answer but also the approach to get there and how to fix the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. If you were not using Lombok annotations then your class Person would have a constructor with @Autowired annotation

```
    @Autowired
    public Person(@Qualifier("vehicle2") Vehicle vehicle) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }
```

This tells Spring to load a bean with @Qualifier("vehicle2") while loading bean of class Person in the context. And this works perfectly fine.

The problem here is the use of Lombok annotations. So with @Data,  `@RequiredArgsConstructor` comes into picture.
And by default Lombok doesn't copy the @Qualifier annotation to the injected constructor.

This was an issue/limitation in Lombok until version 1.18.4. However it is fixed now and you need to add following line in `lombok.config` (if you are not already using this file, then create one `src` folder)

```
lombok.copyableAnnotations += org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier
```

As the key means, it will instruct Lombok to add the Qualifier annotation to the injected constructor.

And this will then work as expected.